# Using angular.js routing inside ng-admin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ng-admin

I have the following problem:
I am using ng-admin to build an administration page. There is a custom page added to the ng-admin interface. The standard ng-admin pages are routed by ng-admin and there is no problem with the list/edit views.
Now I want to use the angular.js routing for the custom page because I need an url routing with parameters in the url.
The routing does works if I don't use any parameters in the url. Once I use the parameters the routing for the custom page does work but when I click any other page the new page is loading forever and not opening. If I use a routing without parameters all pages are loading correctly.

This is working:

```js
function routing($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
// default route
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/custom');
  $stateProvider.state('custom', {
    parent: 'main',
    url: '/custom',
    template: customTemplate,
    controller: 'CustomController'
    });
}
```

This is not working:

```js
function routing($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
// default route
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/custom');
  $stateProvider.state('custom', {
    parent: 'main',
    url: '/custom?date',
    template: customTemplate,
    controller: 'CustomController'
    });
}
```

I use the $state.go function to change the states and route the page:

```js
function transition(){
  var dates = $scope.startdate.getTime();
  $state.go('custom', {date: dates}, {notify: false});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have to declare the parameters in a `params` section:

```js
function routing($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  // default route
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/custom');
  $stateProvider.state('custom', {
    parent: 'main',
    url: '/custom?date',
    params: { date: null },
    template: customTemplate,
    controller: 'CustomController'
  });
}
```

See the [ui-router docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state_parameters) for details.